# Selecting Processname by string containing with WASP in Powershell

Tags: powershell, wasp

I'm trying to select a certain process name within a Powershell script with WASP.  However, the issue is that every time the process is started it gives itself a randomly generated string before the extension.

It does always include the extension ".tmp" though.  Is there anyway I can select the process if it contains .tmp at the end of the string?  In this instance, the process i'm trying to select is "is-RI4E5.tmp".  I'll need to select this based on it containing the extension at the end, ".tmp".

```
 ProcessName    ProcessId IsActive  Handle Title                                                            Class                                
-----------    --------- --------  ------ -----                                                            -----                                
powershell_ise      8652     True  133330 Administrator: Windows PowerShell ISE                            HwndWrapper[PowerShell_ISE.exe;;cf...
is-RI4E5.tmp        6720    False  461306 Setup                                                            TApplication                         
explorer            5472    False  264168 VNC Server                                                       CabinetWClass                        
explorer            5472    False  985230 vnc - Search Results in SharedFiles (\\cas-fs1) (S:)             CabinetWClass                        
chrome              7636    False  329808 Central Arizona Supply - Home - Google Chrome                    Chrome_WidgetWin_1                   
cmd                 7592    False  264396 Administrator: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe                       ConsoleWindowClass                   
EXCEL               8860    False 1116322 Microsoft Excel - CAS Network IP Directory  [Compatibility Mode] XLMAIN                               
EXCEL               8860    False  395668 Printers                                                         MS-SDIb                              
VNCScan             9104    False  198140 Bozteck VENM Console 2013.6.3.230                                WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.378734a
EXCEL               8860    False  461030 CAS Network IP Directory  [Compatibility Mode]                   MS-SDIb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest collecting all the process names prior to starting your WASP process.  Once started, collect all the process again and diff the two collections using Compare-Object.  This will reduce the chance of a false positive when multiple processes have a '.tmp' suffix.

```
$beforeWasp = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -Like '*.tmp' }

# start process here

$afterWasp = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -Like '*.tmp' }

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $beforeWasp -DifferenceObject $afterWasp -PassThru
```

Comment: This was just what I needed!  Thank you, my friend!

Comment: Glad that helped. Please accept answer when you have time.  Thanks.